# Sequelize and PostGIS geometry column not returning proper JSON

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I have a Postgres database with PostGIS running. I'm using Node.js and Sequelize to work with the data within the database. On one of my tables I have a geometry column that is returning weird results.

Normally when I query a geometry column with sequelize I get something along these lines:

```
{ 
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [ 33.48051135141372, -111.92908778058047 ] 
}
```

But for some reason when I log the results from this column I get the following string:

```
01010000004D20CF54F80241409C8C9B8BAE9E5DC0
```

On other tables I'm getting the expected result. But for some reason with this specific table/column I'm unable to parse the latitude and longitude from the data returned.

Can anyone explain why I might be getting this instead of the normal JSON above?

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates must be expressed as `longitude` first, then `latitude`.

Your input is expressed as `lat`-`long`, and so it is out of bounds. Try swapping the coordinates.

Using postgis directly, you can display the textual representation of the geometry:

```
select st_asText('01010000004D20CF54F80241409C8C9B8BAE9E5DC0');
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(34.023203469406 -118.479403402237)
```

which does confirm  that the coordinates are in the wrong order.

Comment: Having this same issue now and just confirmed that my coordinates are correct using this call. Sequelize is only returning this one address from my database as the geostring rather than a Point object. The only difference with this one is that I used findOrCreate to make it instead of just create (but i used the same values i do in my create call for the `defaults` field)